# for Loop will not Iterate

Tags: java

I have written a for loop, and it will only iterate once and I am not sure why. My code is:

```
public static void produceOutputFile() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("created_output_file.txt", true));
    for(int j = 0; j < hashTable.length; j++) {
      System.out.println(hashTable.length);
      System.out.println(j);
      if(hashTable[j] != null) {
        if(hashTable[j].size() > 1) {
          for(int k = 0; k< hashTable[j].size(); j++) {
            outputFile.write((hashTable[j].get(k).getWord()) + " " +(hashTable[j].get(k).getFrequency())+"\n");
            outputFile.flush();
          }
        }
        else {
          outputFile.write((hashTable[j].get(0).getWord()) + " " +(hashTable[j].get(0).getFrequency())+ "\n");
          outputFile.flush();
        }
      }
    }
    outputFile.close();
  }
```

The output is:

```
16
0
```

I am not sure why it will not run 16 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
for(int k = 0; k< hashTable[j].size(); j++) {
```

you're incrementing `j` but using `k` as an index. This loop runs forever since `k` will always be smaller than `hashTable[j].size()` (well, I'm assuming).

Comment: @Connor Actually, when I look at it again, it seems like that should throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If `j` increments forever, `hashTable[j]` would eventually blow up.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It might not, if the very last `hashTable` happens to be empty, then `.size()` becomes 0 and the inner loop terminates, and `j` is at the end so the outer loop terminates as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int k = 0; k< hashTable[j].size(); j++ ) {
        outputFile.write((hashTable[j].get(k).getWord()) + " " +(hashTable[j].get(k).getFrequency())+"\n");
        outputFile.flush();
      }
```

In your inner for loop you increments the J.  so at the first iteration j become  greater than 16. so first loop doesn't iterate for second time. your code should be correct as

```
public static void produceOutputFile() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("created_output_file.txt", true));
    for(int j = 0; j < hashTable.length; j++) {
      System.out.println(hashTable.length);
      System.out.println(j);
      if(hashTable[j] != null) {
        if(hashTable[j].size() > 1) {
          for(int k = 0; k< hashTable[j].size(); k++) {
            outputFile.write((hashTable[j].get(k).getWord()) + " " +(hashTable[j].get(k).getFrequency())+"\n");
            outputFile.flush();
          }
        }
        else {
          outputFile.write((hashTable[j].get(0).getWord()) + " " +(hashTable[j].get(0).getFrequency())+ "\n");
          outputFile.flush();
        }
      }
    }
    outputFile.close();
  }
```

here